# I want to add a series number on duplicates lines

Tags: perl, awk

I have to check find duplicates lines in a file and add a character to the end of the line.
However, I would like to add a series number on the end of each duplicate line.

The data format as following:

```
add sample A1
add sample A2
add sample A2
add sample A3
add sample A3
add sample A3
add sample A4
```

And how to using awk to formatting the data looks like following ?

```
add sample A1
add sample A2
add sample A2_1
add sample A3
add sample A3_1
add sample A3_2
add sample A4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '{count=seen[$0]++; print $0 (count ? "_"count: "")}' file
add sample A1
add sample A2
add sample A2_1
add sample A3
add sample A3_1
add sample A3_2
add sample A4
```

Explanation:

```
count=seen[$0]++     # Increment the number of times this line has been seen
print $0             # Print the line ($0 contains the whole line)
(count?"_"count:"")  # If the count if truthy (>0) also print "_" count
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can write something like

```
awk 'col[$3]++{print $0"_"col[$3]-1;next}1' input
```

- `col[$3]++` The third column is incremented, and saved in associative array `col`. If this count is greater than 1, then the corresponding action of printing the line followed by count is done.
- `print $0` prints the entire record.
- `1` Always true, takes the default action to print the entire line.

**Test**

```
$ awk 'col[$3]++{print $0"_"col[$3]-1;next}1' input
add sample A1
add sample A2
add sample A2_1
add sample A3
add sample A3_1
add sample A3_2
add sample A4
```

Comment: `{print $0"_"col[$3]-1;next}1` might be better as `{$0=$0"_"col[$3]-1}1` since that latter only prints from one common location and avoids the need for `next`.

Answer (score 0):

Perlishly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print;
    my ($doodad) = m{\b(\w+)$};   #grab last word on line
    if ( $seen{$doodad}++ ) {
        print "_", $seen{$doodad} - 1; #print taggy thing if it has been seen. 
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Could condense down to a one liner - and it'd look a bit like the `awk` answer you've got already.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to consider the whole line in your comparison it is more like:

```
awk '{print $0 (done[$0]++ ? "_" done[$0] : "") }'
```

Comment: Although those answers are working for me, however this 1 liner is the best one that I do not modify any variable and fit my requirement.

Comment: @iiSeymour thanks for your explanation, sorry for my poor English and your hard work. Your 1 liner script also useful.